# Copying data from one DataTable to another

Tags: c#, ado.net

What is the fastest way of transferring few thousand rows of data from one DataTable to another? Would be great to see some sample code snippets.

Edit: I need to explain a bit more. There is a filtering condition for copying the rows. So, a plain Copy() will not work.

Comment: Do you need to copy only specific rows or the whole DataTable?

Comment: Only specific rows. Updated the post too.

Comment: Can you filter with a DataView.Filter and then DataTable.Copy?

Comment: Would have worked. but the filtering condition is not that straightforward. It could change depending on some values.

Comment: Are you 100% sure it wouldn't just be easier to refine your original SQL query?

Comment: The SQL query is out of my control :(. Thats the biggest problem I am having.

Comment: The DataTable structure of the source is pathetic. I need to modify that to make it presentable to the UI..

Comment: This appeared in my google search as the 7th result!!! Horray StackOverFlow... Its Working!!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't copy the whole table, you need to copy one rows.  From http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308909 (sample code if you follow the link)

"How to Copy DataRows Between DataTables
Before you use the ImportRow method, you must ensure that the target table has the identical structure as the source table. This sample uses the Clone method of DataTable class to copy the structure of the DataTable, including all DataTable schemas, relations, and constraints.

This sample uses the Products table that is included with the Microsoft SQL Server Northwind database. The first five rows are copied from the Products table to another table that is created in memory."

Comment: It is not exactly a clone. I guess manually iterating through the datatable is the only option..

Answer (score 3):

What is wrong with [DataTable.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.copy.aspx)?

Comment: I need to explain a bit more. There is a filtering condition for copying the rows. So, a plain Copy() will not work.

Answer (score 2):

Copying rows to a table throws some flags at me.  I've seen people try this before, and in every single case what they really wanted was a [System.Data.DataView](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.copy).  You really should check to see if the [RowFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.dataview.rowfilter) property will do what you need it to do.